# Confused about OpenSSL non-blocking I/O

Tags: c, security, ssl, openssl, nonblocking

In general, the OpenSSL library (C API) seems to offer two ways to do everything: you can either use plain system sockets configured to your liking, or you can use OpenSSL `BIO` objects which are sort of like streams.

However, I'm often confused by some of the duplicated functionality.  For example, how do you make an SSL connection non-blocking?  One way seems to be to simply access the underlying file descriptor and set it to non-blocking using `fcntl`.  But there is also an OpenSSL API function called `BIO_set_nbio` which takes in a `BIO*` object and sets it to non-blocking mode.

So what is the best way to set up a non-blocking SSL socket?  What happens if you pass OpenSSL a native file descriptor which is *already* set to non-blocking mode via `fnctl`?  Do you still need to specifically call `BIO_set_nbio` to make the `BIO` object non-blocking?

Answer (score 8):

I think most people prefer the BIO interface, but the BIO routines just use whatever native non-blocking socket APIs that are available on the platform. I don't know what happens if you mix and match.

Note that non-blocking I/O for SSL is *much* trickier than for TCP in general. If you don't understand this going in you're going to be torturing yourself. There are books by [John Viega](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002701) and another by [Eric Rescorla](https://www.amazon.com/Eric-Rescorla/e/B001KD9HP0) that go into this, and you can certainly read the OpenSSL mailing list to get a sense of the heartburn this has caused. Some good code examples showing non-blocking SSL programming with OpenSSL are contained in the software for the [TOR project](https://www.torproject.org/), and the [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) utility.