# Where is the select_wait() function this C code uses?

Tags: c, ssl

While searching for an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054471/a-google-chrome-post-breaks-this-ssl-read-anyone-have-code-that-works) I found [this sample code](http://www.rsa.com/products/bsafe/documentation/mesuite21html/dev_guide/group__SSLCME__SERVER__NBIO.html) which looks like just what I need except it calls

```
select_wait()
```

which is defined in [non_blocking.h](http://www.rsa.com/products/bsafe/documentation/mesuite21html/dev_guide/non__blocking_8h-source.html) but which is otherwise unlocatable.

Is select_wait() proprietary code?  Is it an entrypoint in some DLL I can get?  How do I duplicate whatever select_wait() does?  Does it look safe to simply ignore select_wait() and immediately retry the BIO_read/write calls?

**Update:** In testing the code, the select_wait() appears necessary because BIO_read will hang if input isn't available.  However, RSA's sample code does at most one successful BIO_read before breaking out of the for-loop, so their code also would fail to accept a POST from Chrome as described in the original question.

Comment: why don't you cscope to locate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's part of the proprietary [BSAFE](http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1204) library/framework

Comment: Apparently so, and probably equivalent to BIO_get_fd(bio_con, sock), fd_zero(fdset), fd_set(sock, fdset), select(...).  However, the sample code doesn't work with Chrome POSTs because BIO_read needs to be called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a socket handle, use [select() WinSock API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I think that mixing `select()` and `BIO_read()` may lead to highly confusing results. should be fine if using the lower level `SSL_read` etc though, provided you can handle the extra complexity.

Comment: @Eugene: I don't think there's any correlation between select() and what's ready to read from the SSL buffers.  I going to try the code without select_wait() and see what happens.

Comment: @Eugene: I take that back.  The Openssl BIO_should_retry page says: "one solution is to use non blocking I/O and use a timeout on the select() (or equivalent) call."  I'll give it a try.

Comment: @mike Correct, there could be decrypted buffered plaintext ready to read without blocking, so calling select() could block you unnecessarily.

Comment: @Eugene: And yet SSL servers seem to often rely on select().  I'm thinking it most be possible to hang most SSL servers with ill-formed requests.

Comment: @mike I don't know how OpenSSL implements this. In general, there's a timeout for socket operations in each server, so the thread won't wait forever anyway. And you don't need to use SSL to send a half of request to the server and wait. This is how some DDOS attacks work.