# OpenSSL code works on XP but hangs forever in Vista and up

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl

This code starts [a minimal SSL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054471/a-google-chrome-post-breaks-this-ssl-read-anyone-have-code-that-works):

```
WSAStartup(MakeWord(1,1), WData);
SSL_library_init;
SSL_load_error_strings;
ctx := SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method);
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, 'cert.pem');
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, 'key.pem', 1);
SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx);
bio_ssl := BIO_new_ssl(ctx, 0);
bio_in := BIO_new_accept('443');
BIO_set_accept_bios(bio_in, bio_ssl);
BIO_do_accept(bio_in); // set up the socket
BIO_do_accept(bio_in); // wait for connection
```

Everything works fine on XP.  The code stays in the second BIO_do_accept()
waiting for a connection, and sending an HTTPS request from a browser
causes BIO_do_accept() to return.

On 32-bit Vista Home Premium and 64-bit Windows 7, the second BIO_do_accept() hangs forever, and the browser can't connect.
**Why?**

Changing the 32-bit .EXE's various compatibility modes (Windows XP, Windows NT, etc) has no effect.
I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.0d.

Comment: All the functions which you are using return a status code or a boolean result, so try checking the values for that functions, before the call to the `BIO_do_accept`. because maybe the problem is raised before the call to the `BIO_do_accept` function.

Comment: the real code check()s every call; none of them ever return an error.  the check()s have been left out of the source above to not clutter it up.

Comment: My guess would be that it's to do with UAC. Maybe Vista/Win7 need extra privileges to open/listen on the port. Will it work if you run it as administrator?

Comment: Non-BIO code like that in the server in question 7054471 can establish a connection, so it's not UAC.  The admin account is the only way it has been run.

Comment: Ok. Next guess would be that Win7 machine already has something listening on the required port. After that I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has to do with the double BIO_do_accept() calls.

I took OpenSSL's [S_SERVER.C](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-10/openssl/apps/s_server.c) code, made some changes, and crunched it down to the simpler version below.  It works on Vista and Windows 7!  It uses a completely different set of BIO calls from the problem code above, non-blocking works, and (unlike S_SERVER.C and most server examples on the Net) Google Chrome POSTs are properly grabbed via timeouts per [question 7054471](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054471/a-google-chrome-post-breaks-this-ssl-read-anyone-have-code-that-works).

```
program s_server;

uses sysutils, winsock, windows;

const
  SSLEAY32DLL = 'ssleay32.dll';
  SSL_FILETYPE_PEM  = 1;
  SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN = 1;
  SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN = 2;

function BIO_f_ssl: pointer; cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
function SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx: pointer): BOOL; cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
function SSL_CTX_ctrl(ctx: pointer; cmd, i: integer; p: pointer): integer; cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
procedure SSL_CTX_free(ctx: pointer); cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
function SSL_CTX_new(meth: pointer): pointer; cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
procedure SSL_CTX_set_quiet_shutdown(ctx: pointer; mode: integer); cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
function SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx: pointer; fname: pchar): integer; cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
function SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx: pointer; fname: pchar; itype: integer): integer; cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
procedure SSL_library_init; cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
procedure SSL_load_error_strings; cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
function SSL_new(ctx: pointer): pointer; cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
procedure SSL_set_accept_state(b: pointer); cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
procedure SSL_set_bio(ssl, readbio, writebio: pointer); cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
procedure SSL_set_shutdown(ssl: pointer; mode: integer); cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;
function SSLv23_server_method: pointer; cdecl; external SSLEAY32DLL;

const
  LIBEAY32DLL = 'libeay32.dll';
  BIO_NOCLOSE = $00;
  BIO_CLOSE = $01;

function BIO_ctrl(bp: pointer; cmd: integer; larg: integer; parg: pointer): integer; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
function BIO_f_buffer: pointer; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
procedure BIO_free_all(bp: pointer); cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
function BIO_gets(b: pointer; buf: pchar; size: integer): integer; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
function BIO_int_ctrl(bp: pointer; cmd: integer; i1, i2: integer): integer; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
function BIO_new(t: pointer): pointer; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
function BIO_new_socket(sock, flag: integer): pointer; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
function BIO_push(b: pointer; append: pointer): pointer; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
function BIO_socket_ioctl(sock: integer; ctl: cardinal; p: pointer): integer; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
function BIO_test_flags(bp: pointer; flags: integer): integer; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
function BIO_write(bp, buffer: pointer; size: integer): integer; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;
procedure OPENSSL_load_builtin_modules; cdecl; external LIBEAY32DLL;

function BIO_flush(b: pointer): integer; const BIO_CTRL_FLUSH = 11; begin result := BIO_ctrl(b, BIO_CTRL_FLUSH, 0, nil); end;
function BIO_set_ssl(b, ssl: pointer; c: integer): integer; const BIO_C_SET_SSL = 109; begin result := BIO_ctrl(b, BIO_C_SET_SSL, c, ssl); end;
function BIO_should_retry(b: pointer): boolean; const BIO_FLAGS_SHOULD_RETRY = 8; begin result := BIO_test_flags(b, BIO_FLAGS_SHOULD_RETRY) <> 0; end;
function SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx: pointer; op: integer): integer; const SSL_CTRL_OPTIONS = 32; begin result := SSL_CTX_ctrl(ctx, SSL_CTRL_OPTIONS, op, nil); end;

procedure confirm(b: boolean); begin {$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF} win32check(b); {$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM ON} end;

const
  DEFAULTPORT = 443;
  MAXWAIT = 500; // 500ms max for read

function getresponse(const ip, request: string): string;
var body: string;
begin // ignore request and just announce ip
body := '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Hello!</TITLE></HEAD><H1>Your IP is...</H1><BODY>' + ip + '</BODY></HTML>';
result := 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK'#13#10'Connection: Close'#13#10'Content-Type: text/HTML'#13#10'Content-Length: ' + IntToStr(length(body)) + #13#10#13#10 + body;
end;

const BUFSIZE = 16*1024; // used in openssl s_server.c

var
  buf: packed array[0..BUFSIZE-1] of char;
  request, response: string;
  ctx: pointer;

procedure read_and_respond(const ip: string; sock: integer);
var
  i, j, k: integer; start: cardinal;
  con, io, ssl_bio, sbio: pointer;
label err, endlabel, write_error;
begin
io := BIO_new(BIO_f_buffer);
ssl_bio := BIO_new(BIO_f_ssl); if (io = nil) or (ssl_bio = nil) then goto err;
// enable non-blocking
i := 1; if BIO_socket_ioctl(sock, FIONBIO, @i) < 0 then writeln('Can''t unblock!');
con := SSL_new(ctx); if con = nil then goto err;
sbio := BIO_new_socket(sock, BIO_NOCLOSE);
SSL_set_bio(con, sbio, sbio);
SSL_set_accept_state(con);
BIO_set_ssl(ssl_bio, con, BIO_CLOSE);
BIO_push(io, ssl_bio);
request := ''; start := gettickcount;
repeat
  i := BIO_gets(io, @buf, bufsize-1);
  if i < 0 then // error
    if not BIO_should_retry(io) then goto err
    else continue
  else if i > 0 then
    begin
    buf[i] := #0;
    request := request + buf;
    if length(request) > BUFSIZE then break; // stop malicious request
    end;
until (gettickcount - start) > MAXWAIT; // could also stop if post body == content-length
response := getresponse(ip, request);
i := 1; j := length(response);
while i <= j do
  begin
  k := BIO_write(io, @response[i], j-i+1);
  if k <= 0 then
    if BIO_should_retry(io) then continue
    else break
  else inc(i, k);
  end;
while BIO_flush(io) <= 0 do
  if not BIO_should_retry(io) then break;
SSL_set_shutdown(con, SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN or SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN); // re-use session
err: if io <> nil then BIO_free_all(io); // including ssl_bio
end;

var listen_socket: integer;

procedure do_server;
var server, client: TSockAddr; sock, clientlen: integer;
begin
listen_socket := socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
confirm(listen_socket <> INVALID_SOCKET);
fillchar(server, sizeof(server), 0);
server.sin_family := AF_INET;
server.sin_port := htons(DEFAULTPORT);
server.sin_addr.s_addr := INADDR_ANY;
confirm(bind(listen_socket, server, sizeof(server)) <> INVALID_SOCKET);
confirm(listen(listen_socket, 128) <> INVALID_SOCKET);
while TRUE do
  begin
  fillchar(client, sizeof(client), 0);
  clientlen := sizeof(client);
  sock := accept(listen_socket, @client, @clientlen);
  if sock <> INVALID_SOCKET then
    begin
    read_and_respond(inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), sock);
    shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
    closesocket(sock);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure shutdownserver;
begin
closesocket(listen_socket);
SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
WSAcleanup;
end;

function consolehandler(signal: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
begin // handle some console events
case signal of
  CTRL_C_EVENT, CTRL_BREAK_EVENT: result := TRUE; // handle these by ignoring them
  CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT, CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
    begin
    shutdownserver;
    result := FALSE; // avoid popup
    end
  else result := FALSE; // not handling
  end; // case
end;

procedure main;
var WData: TWSAData;
begin
allocconsole;
confirm(SetConsoleCtrlHandler(@ConsoleHandler, TRUE));
if WSAStartup(MakeWord(2, 2), WData) <> 0 then
  confirm(WSAStartup(MakeWord(1,1), WData) = 0);
SSL_library_init;
SSL_load_error_strings;
OPENSSL_load_builtin_modules;
ctx := SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method); confirm(ctx <> nil);
confirm(SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, 'cert.pem') > 0);
confirm(SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, 'key.pem', SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) > 0);
confirm(SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx));
SSL_CTX_set_quiet_shutdown(ctx, 1);
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, 0);
repeat
  try
    do_server
  except
    on E: Exception do writeln(E.Message);
    end;
until FALSE;
end;

begin
main
end.
```