# How do I get an OpenSSL server using blocking BIO to shutdown cleanly?

Tags: c++, linux, ssl, openssl

In a larger server app I have one thread with a basic OpenSSL server using BIO in blocking mode because that seemed the simplest way. My code accepts a single type of request from a phone (Android or iOS, and I'm not writing that code) and returns a hex string wrapped in basic HTML (describing part of my server state). I've gone with SSL and a psuedo-HTTPS server because that makes things easier for the phone developer. If there's anything in the request that the server doesn't understand I return a 404. This all works.

**The problem** : When my server shuts down this thread doesn't exit because of the blocking BIO_do_accept call.

I have tried BIO_get_fd() and setsockopt() to put a timeout on the underlying socket but it still blocks. Somewhat worryingly SSL_state() stays at "before/accept initialization", but looping on that obviously won't work.

I assume other people have server code like this, and those servers can shut down gracefully. How do they do that? Is there some way for another thread to break that block and get the accept call to return with an error? Or do I have to drop the idea of blocking calls and grind through the [apparently awful non-blocking version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397788/confused-about-openssl-non-blocking-i-o/5398995#5398995)?

Answer (score 2):

> When my server shuts down this thread doesn't exit because of the blocking BIO_do_accept call.

To stop the blocking, close the associated socket. It will return immediately.

Perform the shutdown from your signal handler.

Don't do anything else in the signal handler with respect to OpenSSL because it is not async-signal safe. Let the main thread cleanup once your worker thread has returned. See, for example, [`libcrypto` Thread Safety](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libcrypto_API#Thread_Safety).

Comment: Unfortunately closing the socket has no effect, nor does BIO_reset. BIO_free causes a SIGSEGF (which does exit the program). I've gone with starting a connection from the close-calling thread so that the BIO_accept unblocks and sees the shutdown flag.