# OpenSSL non-blocking mode BIO

Tags: c++, openssl, nonblocking

I am trying to create a non-blocking bio OpenSSL server, looking at [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397788/confused-about-openssl-non-blocking-i-o) didn't help, I was trying with BIO_set_nbio(), but to no avail (see code snippet below).

Can someone please help me and hopefully explain why the one-line call to BIO_set_nbio doesn't appear to do what it says on the tin....

```
BIO *ssl_bio;
SSL_CTX *ctx;
BIO *in = NULL;

SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
ssl_bio = BIO_new_ssl(ctx, 0);

SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

if ((in = BIO_new_accept(port)) == NULL)
    goto err;

BIO_set_nbio( ssl_bio, 1 );
BIO_set_nbio( in, 1 );

BIO_set_accept_bios(in, ssl_bio);
```

Comment: In my server implementation, I create an overlapped I/O server socket, accept a client on it, then call `ssl_new()`, `BIO_new()` to create 2 memory BIOs, `SSL_set_bio()` to link them to the `SSL`, and `SSL_set_accept_state()` to start the handshake process. From that point on, I manage my own overlapped socket I/O operations using `WSASend()` and `WSARecv()`, using the memory BIOs to push data through the OpenSSL system in both directions (decrypting incoming data and encrypting outgoing data). I don't let OpenSSL do the socket I/O for me.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hi, I am familiar with non-blocking using winsock/socket, how do you send()/recv() using the memory bio please?  Any chance you can add some code snippets please.  Thank you.

Comment: There are plenty of online articles that explain how to use memory BIOs with non-blocking sockets, for instance, [Use OpenSSL with Asynchronous Sockets, I/O Completion Ports and Ceritificate Signing](https://famellee.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/use-openssl-with-io-completion-port-and-certificate-signing/) and [Using OpenSSL with memory BIOs](http://www.roxlu.com/2014/042/using-openssl-with-memory-bios)...

Comment: ... The concept is simple: create 2 memory `BIO` pairs, one for input and one for output. Link the input `BIO` to the `SSL`'s input, and the output `BIO` to the `SSL`'s output. Read encrypted data from the socket as needed and `BIO_write()` it into the input `BIO`, then call `SSL_read()` to let OpenSSL consume it.  Whenever you write something with `SSL_write()`, call `BIO_read()` to read OpenSSL's generated encrypted data from the output `BIO` and send it to the socket as needed.

Comment: For example of server, using memory BIO, see this gist: https://gist.github.com/darrenjs/4645f115d10aa4b5cebf57483ec82eca